# Object.toString() show the wrong class?

Tags: java, tostring

I had a strange issue while debugging some code.

Here is the relevant I use to test something (we don't care here what I test):

```
private void launch(){
        System.out.println("DIAGNOSIS ");
        System.out.println("commands size: "+commands.size());
        System.out.println("commands top element: "+commands.peek());
        SimpleCommand command = commands.peek();
        System.out.println("simple command peek :"+command);

        if(!isEmpty()) {
            commands.peek().apply();
            countDown.reset(delays.peek());
            countDown.run();
        }
    }
```

And here, what I the debug window shows me:

[image: debug screen]

As you can see when I call toString() on an instance of SimpleCommand.class
It shows that the given object is in fact a BattleInteractionMachine.class (BIM). It should be obvious but I want to specify that I haven't override the toString method from Object.class

Yet, those two classes are not related to each other

SimpleCommand inherance tree: SimpleCommand < Command < Object

BIM inherance tree:  BIM < MachineState < Object

I am totally clueless on how it is even possible...
Any idea about how it can happen? I don't seek a specific answer to my case but rather a general understanding on how this issue can rise.

Comment: There’s no getting around it; `BattleInteractionMachine` must override `toString()`. You could put some fancy reflection code in to assert all commands implement their own `toString()`, but I would advise against it.

Comment: Try to create a [mcve] and [edit] your question.

Comment: How is `commands` defined and populated?

Comment: Could you please post the class declarations and `toString` methods of the related classes (BattleInteractionMachine, MachineState, SimpleCommand and Command?

Comment: Basically,  `BattleInteractionMachine` is not an instance of `SimpleCommand`. So why does this line `SimpleCommand command = commands.peek();` not fail?

Comment: I guess `SimpleCommand` and it's hierarchy are interfaces and it's at some point implemented in the hierarchy of `BattleInteractionMachine` otherwise the code wouldn't compile, or you'd get class cast exception. The fact, that variable command is declared as `SimpleCommand` doesn't anyhow say, what the refered object really is. It can be anything that extends or implements `SimpleCommand`. So important is, what `commands.peek()` really returns.

Comment: [Never post pictures of text when you can post the actual text. Be sure that it is properly formatted and readable.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object returned from `commands.peek()` is *not* a `BattleInteractionMachine` object.

You missed the **`$3`** part of the displayed name, which is part of the class name of the returned object. Anything before the `@` sign is the fully qualified class name.

The `$` and number suffix means that the object is an instance of an **anonymous class** defined inside the `BattleInteractionMachine` class.

The number 3 would indicate that BIM declares at least two other anonymous classes, since numbering generally starts with 1. If you can see the `BattleInteractionMachine.class` on your file system or in a `.jar` file, you'll also see other `BattleInteractionMachine$XXX.class` files, where XXX can be a number or a name or something more complex.

E.g. something like this:

```
class BattleInteractionMachine {
    // ...
    void somemethod() {
        // ...
        SimpleCommand command = new SimpleCommand() {
            // methods here
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I noticed that if the SimpleCommand instance was not an anonymous class, the toString() method recognise my class's instance but I haven't notice the $3. Your answer now made it clear why!